# How to redirect touch events from the child to the parent layout?

Tags: android

I tried to implement a `DatePicker`-like behaviour using only `TextView`, `EditText` and `ImageView`. You can see the result on the folloing picture:

[image]

The reason why i did that is simple: I cant style a regular `DatePicker` to look like that one on the picture above. I now have the look that i want and i also implemented a kind of scrolling but there are some problems left. For example we are taking the first year of the first date shown on the picture. There you can see an up arrow (`ImageView`), the year (`EditText`) and an down arrow (`ImageView`) and they are all nested inside a vertical `LinearLayout`.

I now added a gesture recognizer to each of these layouts:

```
public class MyClass extends DialogFragment implements OnTouchListener, OnGestureListener {

    ...

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector = null;

    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setRetainInstance(true);
        this.gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this.getActivity(), this);
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ...

        this.layoutFromDay = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.date_selection_layout_from_day);
        this.layoutFromDay.setOnTouchListener(this);
        this.layoutFromMonth = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.date_selection_layout_from_month);
        this.layoutFromMonth.setOnTouchListener(this);
        this.layoutFromYear = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.date_selection_layout_from_year);
        this.layoutFromYear.setOnTouchListener(this);
        this.layoutToDay = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.date_selection_layout_to_day);
        this.layoutToDay.setOnTouchListener(this);
        this.layoutToMonth = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.date_selection_layout_to_month);
        this.layoutToMonth.setOnTouchListener(this);
        this.layoutToYear = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.date_selection_layout_to_year);
        this.layoutToYear.setOnTouchListener(this);

        ...
    }

    ...

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        motionEvent.setSource(view.getId());

        return this.gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent motionEvent1, MotionEvent motionEvent2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent motionEvent1, MotionEvent motionEvent2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        LinearLayout sourceView = this.getSourceView(motionEvent1.getSource());

        Log.v("DataSelectionDialogFragment", "OnScroll Called");

        if(sourceView != null) {

            Log.v("DataSelectionDialogFragment", "SouceView not null");
            if(motionEvent1.getY() > motionEvent2.getY() && velocityY > 10) {

                Log.v("DataSelectionDialogFragment", "Scroll Up");
                if(sourceView.equals(this.layoutFromDay)) {
                    int currentValue = Integer.parseInt(this.editTextFromDay.getText().toString());

                    if(currentValue < 31) {
                        this.editTextFromDay.setText("" + ++currentValue);
                    }
                } else if(sourceView.equals(layoutToDay)) {
                    int currentValue = Integer.parseInt(this.editTextToDay.getText().toString());

                    if(currentValue < 31) {
                        this.editTextToDay.setText("" + ++currentValue);
                    }
                } else if(sourceView.equals(layoutFromMonth)) {
                    int currentValue = Integer.parseInt(this.editTextFromMonth.getText().toString());

                    if(currentValue < 12) {
                        this.editTextFromMonth.setText("" + ++currentValue);
                    }
                } else if(sourceView.equals(layoutToMonth)) {
                    int currentValue = Integer.parseInt(this.editTextToMonth.getText().toString());

                    if(currentValue < 12) {
                        this.editTextToMonth.setText("" + ++currentValue);
                    }
                } else if(sourceView.equals(layoutFromYear)) {
                    int currentValue = Integer.parseInt(this.editTextFromYear.getText().toString());

                    this.editTextFromYear.setText("" + ++currentValue);
                } else if(sourceView.equals(layoutToYear)) {
                    int currentValue = Integer.parseInt(this.editTextToYear.getText().toString());

                    this.editTextToYear.setText("" + ++currentValue);
                }
            } else if(motionEvent1.getY() < motionEvent2.getY() && velocityY < 10) {
                Log.v("DataSelectionDialogFragment", "Scroll Down");

                if(sourceView.equals(this.layoutFromDay)) {
                    int currentValue = Integer.parseInt(this.editTextFromDay.getText().toString());

                    if(currentValue > 1) {
                        this.editTextFromDay.setText("" + --currentValue);
                    }
                } else if(sourceView.equals(layoutToDay)) {
                    int currentValue = Integer.parseInt(this.editTextToDay.getText().toString());

                    if(currentValue > 1) {
                        this.editTextToDay.setText("" + --currentValue);
                    }
                } else if(sourceView.equals(layoutFromMonth)) {
                    int currentValue = Integer.parseInt(this.editTextFromMonth.getText().toString());

                    if(currentValue > 1) {
                        this.editTextFromMonth.setText("" + --currentValue);
                    }
                } else if(sourceView.equals(layoutToMonth)) {
                    int currentValue = Integer.parseInt(this.editTextToMonth.getText().toString());

                    if(currentValue > 1) {
                        this.editTextToMonth.setText("" + --currentValue);
                    }
                } else if(sourceView.equals(layoutFromYear)) {
                    int currentValue = Integer.parseInt(this.editTextFromYear.getText().toString());

                    if(currentValue > 1970) {
                        this.editTextFromYear.setText("" + --currentValue);
                    }
                } else if(sourceView.equals(layoutToYear)) {
                    int currentValue = Integer.parseInt(this.editTextToYear.getText().toString());

                    if(currentValue > 1970) {
                        this.editTextToYear.setText("" + --currentValue);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return true;
    }

    ...

    private LinearLayout getSourceView(int source) {
        switch(source) {
        case R.id.date_selection_layout_from_day:
            return this.layoutFromDay;
        case R.id.date_selection_layout_from_month:
            return this.layoutFromMonth;
        case R.id.date_selection_layout_from_year:
            return this.layoutFromYear;
        case R.id.date_selection_layout_to_day:
            return this.layoutToDay;
        case R.id.date_selection_layout_to_month:
            return this.layoutToMonth;
        case R.id.date_selection_layout_to_year:
            return this.layoutToYear;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

So as you can see i add a `OnTouchListener` to each `LinearLayout`. In the `onTouch` method i save the id of the source layout into the `MotionEvent`.
In my `onScroll` method i can now find out which of my `LinearLayout`'s was the source of the scroll event. Comparing the Y-Values of the first and the second `MotionEvent`'s i can now decide if it was a scroll down or a scroll up and can change the values in my `EditText`'s.

**Now to my Problem:**

The scrolling is working... but... not always. It is hard to explain, sometimes i scroll for 10 seconds or longer and nothing happens and sometimes the scrolling happens just instantly. I could not find any pattern for when it works and when it does not work so i have to ask for help here. I guess i have already done a quite good work and there is just an inch missing to reach my goal.

I hope someone can help me with that problem.

**EDIT-2**

I was able to break down the code to make it easier to understand. Take the following Layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/date_selection_layout_from_day"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/date_selection_edittext_from_day"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/date_selection_edittext_from_month"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/textcolorprimary"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

When i set the `OnTouchListener` to be on my `EditText`:

```
this.editTextFromDay = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.date_selection_edittext_from_day);
this.editTextFromDay.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Everything works like a charm but when i set it to the layout instead:

```
this.layoutFromDay = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.date_selection_layout_from_day);
this.layoutFromDay.setOnTouchListener(this);

this.editTextFromDay = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.date_selection_edittext_from_day);
this.editTextFromDay.setEnabled(false);
```

The OnTouch is never reacting when i scroll over the `EditText`. That means the `EditText` is consuming the `OnTouch` even when its disabled. So my question has changed now to: How can i let my child-views ignore the touch events and redirect them to my parent layout? I want all touch events inside the layout to be called from the layout and not from its child views.

**EDIT-3**

I cant use `onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)` because my code is in a 
`DialogFragment` from the support package.

Comment: shot in the dark...I did not understood everything you trying to achieve, but it sounds that your `onTouch`-Event is handled wrong. It sounds like you re `onTouch`-event is taken from a view, which has no Event-Listener, and therefore other TouchEvents are not delegated? Try to add a `log message` in your onTouch to determine, if you get a log message if it s not scrolling.

Comment: It is somehow delaying. I always have to scroll multiple times. The first one to three times nothing is happening but after that all the scrolling motions i made are fired. After that again a variable amount of times nothing happens when i scroll but all events are fired at any time when i keep scrolling. And sometimes i get the error message: 01-27 15:04:32.658: W/InputEventSender(17724): Failed to send key event on channel 'ClientState{179e2353 uid 10161 pid 17724} (server)'.  status=-11

Comment: Why are you using a `ScrollView` when it doesn't handle any scrolling? Do you need to use an `EditText` if you're utilizing a spinner? You can implement a subclass of `LinearLayout` and override the `onInterceptTouchEvent()` callback method in it?

Comment: Ofcourse it handles scrolling - when the keyboard pops up! The original DatePicker also uses an EditText to let the user manullay type in the numbers using the Keyboard, i wanted to provide the same behaviour.

Comment: @Mulgard: OK. Try my last suggestion though, it should accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've a suggestion for you, which may sound like a workaround but which will let you achieve your goal.

**1)** Inject a raw `View` on top of all other elements in your current hierarchy. This `View` will be your **overlay touch layer**.

```
 <!-- Other XML childs here -->

<View
    android:id="@+id/touch_layer"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**2)** Get a reference to the *touch_layer* and attach a custom **[OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html)**

```
touchLayer.setOnTouchListener(new OverlayTouchListener());
```

**3)** Define your custom **OverlayTouchListener** implementing `OnTouchListener`. Now, this is the critical part in which you have to establish what to do with your `MotionEvent` while avoiding to let it "passes" when is not needed by returning *true* in the `onTouch()` method (this logic is up to you :P ). In this way, you can avoid that some `View` consumes the event, because you are on top of everyone else!

The key point here is to figure out **where the user is tapping**. For this reason I post the following method to check if a `MotionEvent` intercepts a `View` with some tolerance (it can be used easly inside the `onTouch()` ):

```
    /**
     * Useful mathod to detemines if a touchevent can be relevant for the provided view
     * @param ev
     * @param view
     * @param boundingBoxTolerance >= 1 means higher tap-tolerance (bigger bounding-box). Values < 1.0 are handled like 1.0f 
     * @return
     */
    private boolean intercept(MotionEvent ev, View view, float boundingBoxTolerance){
        if( view == null )
            return false;

        if(boundingBoxTolerance < 1.0f){
            boundingBoxTolerance = 1.0f;
        }
        try{
            if(ev != null && view != null){
                int coords[] = new int[2];
                view.getLocationOnScreen( coords );
                if(ev.getX() >= ((float)coords[0]) / boundingBoxTolerance  && ev.getX() <= coords[0] + ((float)view.getWidth())*boundingBoxTolerance){
                    if(ev.getY() >= ((float)coords[1]) / boundingBoxTolerance && ev.getY() <= coords[1] +  ((float)view.getHeight())*boundingBoxTolerance)
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            //exception
        }

        return false;
    }
```

The *boundingBoxTolerance* parameter is useful because you can tune the precision necessary for a particular gesture over a `View`.

So, what do you have to do? you just have to implement the `onTouch()` method accordingly to your logic, just remember to return *true* when you don't want to let the `MotionEvent` passes through.